# Cannot move content view in cells in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I can't change a position and size of title and subtitle label in Interface Builder. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you set the cell's type to `Custom`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't edit the position of the default `UITableViewCell` subviews in interface builder. You can change the text alignment, content insets, and other related properties but you can't explicitly change their frames. You can do this in code when you are displaying the cells themselves as some other answers point out, but I recommend against doing this as it can cause some other side effects when Apple makes changes to these components.

If you need to customize the position of these subviews, you should instead just build them manually. You can do this in interface builder by selecting the cell, then selecting the 4th tab on the right (Attributes Inspector), then change the Style to Custom. Once you do this, the default subviews will disappear in interface builder and you can just add your own.

Answer (score 0):

You have chosen the default cell style for your cell. The **Title** and **Subtitle** labels for the chosen style you see are some basic UI controls that are meant to be used for typical scenarios of displaying content in a tableView usually. If the framing of the labels are comfortable and okay to you, then it is fine. If not, you need to make your own custom style cell.

Basically you cannot modify the default cell style that Apple provides. Just make the cell style **Custom** and do whatever you want with the layout.